# creating table by rank then comparing it

Tags: r

On a data that includes, different cities, year, and generosity--need to create a table with the 15 cities who have the highest average generosity scores over the five years of the data. How would I do it?

```
Year    Cities  generosity  economic    culture     hp
2000    Seoul   1.33358 0.35637 1.30923 0.65124
2001    Mexico City 1.22857 0.07785 1.22393 0.41319
2002    Guangzhou   0.95578 0.10583 1.23788 0.63376
2003    Beijing 1.33723 0.18676 1.29704 0.62433
2004    Cairo   1.02054 0.21312 0.91451 0.48181
2005    New York    1.39451 0.1589  1.24711 0.54604
2006    Kolkata 0.98124 0.17521 1.23287 0.49049
2007    Moscow  1.56391 0.37798 1.21963 0.61583
2008    Bangkok 1.33596 0.28703 1.36948 0.61777
2009    Buenos Aires    1.30782 0.2254  1.28566 0.5845
2010    Shenzhen    1.42727 0.38583 1.12575 0.64157
2011    Dhaka   1.26637 0.32067 1.28548 0.59625
2012    Lagos   1.04424 0.11069 1.25596 0.42908
2013    Istanbul    1.52186 0.4921  1.02    0.54252
2014    Osaka   1.06353 0.0927  1.1985  0.5421
2015    Karachi 1.32792 0.21843 1.29937 0.61477
```

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that you agreed to on joining the site.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do this as :

```
df1 <- aggregate(generosity~Cities, df, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
result <- head(df1[order(df1$generosity), ], 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using {dplyr}

EDIT: I assumed you meant top 5 cities over 15 years of data.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dat <- tribble(~Year,~Cities,~generosity,~economic,~culture,~hp,
        2000,"Seoul",1.33358,0.35637,1.30923,0.65124,2001,"Mexico City",1.22857,0.07785,1.22393,0.41319,2002,"Guangzhou",0.95578,0.10583,1.23788,0.63376,2003,"Beijing",1.33723,0.18676,1.29704,0.62433,2004,"Cairo",1.02054,0.21312,0.91451,0.48181,2005,"New York",1.39451,0.1589,1.24711,0.54604,2006,"Kolkata",0.98124,0.17521,1.23287,0.49049,2007,"Moscow",1.56391,0.37798,1.21963,0.61583,2008,"Bangkok",1.33596,0.28703,1.36948,0.61777,2009,"Buenos Aires",1.30782,0.2254,1.28566,0.5845,2010,"Shenzhen",1.42727,0.38583,1.12575,0.64157,2011,"Dhaka",1.26637,0.32067,1.28548,0.59625,2012,"Lagos",1.04424,0.11069,1.25596,0.42908,2013,"Istanbul",1.52186,0.4921,1.02,0.54252,2014,"Osaka",1.06353,0.0927,1.1985,0.5421,2015,"Karachi",1.32792,0.21843,1.29937,0.61477)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Cities) %>% 
  summarize(avg_generosity = mean(generosity)) %>%
  arrange(desc(avg_generosity)) %>%
  head(5)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   Cities   avg_generosity
#>   <chr>             <dbl>
#> 1 Moscow             1.56
#> 2 Istanbul           1.52
#> 3 Shenzhen           1.43
#> 4 New York           1.39
#> 5 Beijing            1.34
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>